# TSQL Dynamic Pivot with two alternating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has multiple payments to clients on multiple dates that looks like this:

```
Claimid  Payorder   Date Raised  Amount
79         1        05/12/2013   120000.00
79         2        19/10/2013   1138873.90
79         3        29/10/2013   150000.00
79         4        30/10/2013   11126.10
678        1        09/02/2006   467207.65
```

I need to pivot the data so that it would look like this:

```
[Claimid]  [Date_Raised_1] [Payment_1]  [Date_Raised_2]  [Payment_2]
 79        05/12/2013        120000      19/10/2013       1138873.9
```

Can anyone help me with this?  - it needs to be dynamic too as any claim can have many payments..

Comment: Tag your question properly. `TSQL` is being used in `SQL Server`, which is different product than `MySQL`.

Comment: Ah. Thank you - I think one was added automatically when I created the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I came up with:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample
(
    ClaimId INT
    , PayOrder INT
    , DateRaised DATE
    , Amount FLOAT
);

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT ClaimId';

INSERT INTO #Sample (ClaimId, PayOrder, DateRaised, Amount)
VALUES (79, 1, CONVERT(DATE, '05/12/2013', 103), 120000.00)
    , (79, 2, CONVERT(DATE, '19/10/2013', 103), 1138873.90)
    , (79, 3, CONVERT(DATE, '29/10/2013', 103), 150000.00)
    , (79, 4, CONVERT(DATE, '30/10/2013', 103), 11126.10)
    , (678, 1, CONVERT(DATE, '09/02/2006', 103), 467207.65);

SELECT @SQL += '
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = ' + PayOrder + ' THEN DateRaised END) AS [DateRaised_' + PayOrder + ']
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = ' + PayOrder + ' THEN Amount END) AS [Payment_' + PayOrder + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR, PayOrder) AS PayOrder FROM #Sample) AS T
ORDER BY T.PayOrder;

SET @SQL += 'FROM #Sample GROUP BY ClaimId;';

EXECUTE (@SQL);

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

This query will generate columns for each `DISTINCT PayOrder` and generate following query in your test-case:

```
SELECT ClaimId
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 1 THEN DateRaised END) AS [DateRaised_1]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 1 THEN Amount END) AS [Payment_1]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 2 THEN DateRaised END) AS [DateRaised_2]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 2 THEN Amount END) AS [Payment_2]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 3 THEN DateRaised END) AS [DateRaised_3]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 3 THEN Amount END) AS [Payment_3]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 4 THEN DateRaised END) AS [DateRaised_4]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN PayOrder = 4 THEN Amount END) AS [Payment_4]
FROM #Sample
GROUP BY ClaimId;
```

That's the output:

```
╔═════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╦═══════════╗
║ ClaimId ║ DateRaised_1 ║ Payment_1 ║ DateRaised_2 ║ Payment_2 ║ DateRaised_3 ║ Payment_3 ║ DateRaised_4 ║ Payment_4 ║
╠═════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╬═══════════╣
║      79 ║ 2013-12-05   ║ 120000    ║ 2013-10-19   ║ 1138873.9 ║ 2013-10-29   ║ 150000    ║ 2013-10-30   ║ 11126.1   ║
║     678 ║ 2006-02-09   ║ 467207.65 ║ NULL         ║ NULL      ║ NULL         ║ NULL      ║ NULL         ║ NULL      ║
╚═════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Ignore date format, mines set as `YYYY-MM-DD`. It should be displayed as `DD/MM/YYYY` on your machine.

Comment: Thank you @Evaldas Buinauskas. Much appreciated - you're a star!!

Comment: @AJCT I'm glad this helped :)

Comment: Just wanted to say this has been such a useful piece of code to me over the last three years! Thanks once again!

Comment: Haha. This is fascinating. Cheers @AJCT!